# ERROR: Could not find credentials entry with ID '${TEST}'

Tags: jenkins, cron, credentials

I have a problem with passing credentials to Jenkin's job during the scheduled build with parameters. The parameter is required and it has default value.
When I execute the job manually everything works ok, but during scheduled execution when I try to pass different credential than the default, it finishes with fail and message:

> ERROR: Could not find credentials entry with ID '${TEST}'

Parameters I passing:

> H 5 * * * % TEST=CREDENTIAL_TEST_ID

[Credential parameter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7TS1M.png)
[Binding credentials](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uCgyy.png)

Does it possible to use the credentials parameter in scheduled build, or I do something in wrong way?

Comment: I have the same problem where I have a job with a dynamic parameter ID. The job runs fine when run manually but I'd like to have it build periodically.

Comment: @mickadoo Did you set "Run as SYSTEM" for projects build authorization? See https://stackoverflow.com/a/72847599/658497

Comment: Thanks for the reply @NoamManos - I think I just gave up in the end :-D

Answer (score 3):

I am facing the same issue and found https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-32402. The only "solution" currently seems to be to give user 'Anonymous' permission for 'Configure Job'. This way I was able to workaround this issue, but looking for better solutions.

Answer (score 2):

In `Manage Jenkins -> Configure Global Security`, toward the middle of page there's a section called `Access Control For Builds`. Set the `Strategy` to `Run as SYSTEM`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe obvious question, but to confirm, are you using build trigger "Build periodically with parameters"?

Additionally, are you trying to to schedule the build with parameter which should read credentials from Jenkins Credentials? - if yes, this could be a problem as credentials passed to build via any plugins, are passed when the build steps are being executed and not on the "parameters" stage.

I assume, when you run project manually, the value provided for "TEST" parameter is identical to the one specified in scheduled run - am I correct?

Comment: Yes, I am using "Build periodically with parameters" to trigger build.

For your second question, the answer is also yes, I try to pass credentials (secret text) from Jenkins credentials.

I think I should add that before creating of cron I executed my job manually and I checked the credential ID via echo command and then I used this ID as cron parameter.

Comment: Since you are mentioning cron, I believe the job is a pipeline. I am curious to see that solution, would you mind sharing your script, once sorted?

Comment: It is just Jenkins job, not pipeline, sorry if I was not precise. I wanted to say that to check what value is passed to TEST param (which I try to bind to variable contain password - BINDED_TEST) and ensure whether it is credential id I executed my job by hand. The job in logs returned me id which I used later in the same in "Build periodically with parameters" in parameters which I pasted in my first message. Summarizing, I executed the job manually for the first time, and then I tried to execute it again with the scheduler with passed paramaters.

Comment: Same problem. I think it is a bug. Did you solve it?

Comment: No. I had to create job with the hardcoded binding of credentials. In job settings, in "Build environment" I used "Use secret text(s) or file(s)" option and I selected the credential I need to bind with variable from the list. I am using "Credentials Plugin" with version 2.3.14 and Credentials Bind Plugin version: 1.24